# mysql doesn't connect while using fopen

Tags: php, mysql

The code below doesn't connect:

```
$file_open = fopen("logindetails.txt","r");

if($file_open){
    $user = fgets($file_open);
    $pass = fgets($file_open);
    $server = fgets($file_open);
}
echo "user: ",$user,"password: ",$pass,"server: ",$server;
@$db_handle = mysql_connect($server,$user,$pass);
```

but outputs:

```
user: root password: usbw server: localhost
```

logindetails.txt contains:

```
root
usbw
localhost
```

while this code connects:

```
$user = "root";
$pass = "usbw";
$server = "localhost";

echo "user: ",$user,"password: ",$pass,"server: ",$server;
@$db_handle = mysql_connect($server,$user,$pass);
```

I can't get this working and I can't guess why.

Comment: Are you sure the credentials is correct?

Comment: Yes. I think it has something to do with string.I don't get it at all.

Answer (score 1):

The variables you read with `fgets` in also contain linebreaks.

```
$user == "root\n";
$pass == "passw\n";
```

Which is why MySQL won't recognize them as valid.

So, you should either:

- `trim()` them
- instead use an INI file
- better yet some `config.php` instead of a text file.